# ReactJS how to delete item from list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have have code that creates `<li>` elements. I need to delete elements one by one by clicking. For each element I have `Delete button`. I understand that I need some function to delete items by `id`. How to do this function to delete elements in ReactJS?
My code:

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.state = {items: [], text: ''};
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>TODO</h3>
                <TodoList items={this.state.items} />
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.text} />
                    <button>{'Add #' + (this.state.items.length + 1)}</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({text: e.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var newItem = {
            text: this.props.w +''+this.props.t,
            id: Date.now()
        };
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            items: prevState.items.concat(newItem),
            text: ''
        }));
    }

    delete(id){          // How that function knows id of item that need to delete and how to delete item?
        this.setState(this.item.id)
    }
}

class TodoList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.props.items.map(item => (
                    <li key={item.id}>{item.text}<button onClick={this.delete.bind(this)}>Delete</button></li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You are managing the data in Parent component and rendering the UI in Child component, so to delete item from child component you need to pass a function along with data, call that function from child and pass any unique identifier of list item, inside parent component delete the item using that unique identifier.

**Step1:** Pass a function from parent component along with data, like this:

```
<TodoList items={this.state.items} _handleDelete={this.delete.bind(this)}/>
```

**Step2:** Define `delete` function in parent component like this:

```
delete(id){
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        data: prevState.data.filter(el => el != id )
    }));
}
```

**Step3:** Call that function from child component using `this.props._handleDelete()`:

```
class TodoList extends React.Component {

    _handleDelete(id){
        this.props._handleDelete(id);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.props.items.map(item => (
                    <li key={item.id}>{item.text}<button onClick={this._handleDelete.bind(this, item.id)}>Delete</button></li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
```

Check this working example:

```js
class App extends React.Component{
   constructor(){
      super();
      this.state = {
        data: [1,2,3,4,5]
      }
      this.delete = this.delete.bind(this);
   }
   
   delete(id){
      this.setState(prevState => ({
          data: prevState.data.filter(el => el != id )
      }));
   }
   
   render(){
      return(
          <Child delete={this.delete} data={this.state.data}/>
      );
   }
}

class Child extends React.Component{

   delete(id){
       this.props.delete(id);
   }
   
   render(){
      return(
         <div>
           {
              this.props.data.map(el=>
                  <p onClick={this.delete.bind(this, el)}>{el}</p>
              )
           }
         </div>
      )
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: it gives me id in console. and how to delete it?

Comment: check the updated answer, added the functions to delete the item from array.

Comment: thanks for code example, can you please explain that means  `data = data.filter(el => el != id );`

Comment: filter is used to filter out the data from array, if you return true it will put that value inside new array and if you return false it will ignore that array value, by using filter i am checking which element is having the same id, if id is same then return false, otherwise true, check this link it will explain everything: https://danmartensen.svbtle.com/javascripts-map-reduce-and-filter

Comment: Just adding a quick note: you'd be using 'filter' here since you should not mutate the state.

Comment: You could also use `<p onClick={this.props.delete.bind(this, el)}>{el}</p>` and avoid creating another function in the child component. Nevertheless, great answer.