# REACT: How can I delete this without using unique id?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

**I want to delete this TODO with or without using a unique key**

**this is the HOOK code**

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([{}])
const [user, setUser] = useState({
    id: uuidv4(),
    name: '',
    email: '',
    phone: '',
})
```

> This one is the Function to set Input and delete a todo

```
const addTodo = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setTodos([...todos, user])
    console.log(addTodo)
}
console.log(user)
const delTodo = (e, id) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(id)
    todos.splice(id, 1)
    setTodos([...todos])
}
```

> Here These are being mapped

```
{todos.map((todo) => (
                    <div>
                        <li key={todo.id}>
                            {todo.name}, {todo.email}, {todo.phone}
                        </li>
                        <button onClick={delTodo} color='danger'>
                            Delete
                        </button>
                    </div>
                ))}
```

> This is what i get when i console.log

[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yne6O.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `delTodo` function as below.

[splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) uses first parameter as `start index` from array that you want to remove and second parameter is `deleteCount`. So in your case you need to get `index` of your `object`.

You can get `index` of `object` with [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). It will return `-1` of `object` does not belong to that array. So add `if (index != -1) { }` and then you can use `todos.splice(index, 1);` inside it.

```
const delTodo = (e, id) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(id);
    let index = todos.indexOf(id);
    if (index != -1) {
        todos.splice(index, 1);
    }
    setTodos([...todos]);
}
```

Comment: i got it, but how would I call it with onClick delete button?I tried this code but its not deleting any value

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230622/reactjs-how-to-delete-item-from-list/43230714